# MUI5 :Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'primary')

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using MUI5 with reactjs and I wanted to use the makeStyles to add some custom CSS to the MUI components but its not allowing me to use the default theme inside the makestyles so my code is :

```
import { Grid, Card, CardContent,Typography, CardActions,Button, AppBar, Toolbar, 
Box,IconButton, Menu, MenuItem, InputBase, alpha, styled, Badge, Container, CardHeader, 
CardMedia  } from '@mui/material';
import EmailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Email';
import NotificationsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Notifications';

import React from 'react' 

import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: ({
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
    color: theme.color,
  }),
}));
const App = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return(
    <Fragment>
      <Container className={classes.root}>
        <Typography>
          this is a very random text to fill
        </Typography>
      </Container>
    </Fragment>
  )
}

 export default App;
```

its not allowing me to get to the theme props inside the makestyles

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try assigning "root" as a normal object property like this-

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
    color: theme.color,
  }
}));
```

If it does not work, you may want to take a look at this-
https://mui.com/styles/basics/#using-the-theme-context

Comment: I First assigned it normally then I tried to get an instantaneous return and it didn't work either . Actually my code is taken from the documentation it's the first example of using the theme inside the makeStyles but I didn't know if Iam doing something wrong or Its not working anymore on the mui5